# How to use fix error "does not exist on type string | interface" or can I use satisfies in a useState?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, tsx

I have the next interfaces

```
interface ICustomImage {
  data: string;
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

type UserImage = string | ICustomImage

interface IUser {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  image: UserImage
}
```

And I'm getting the IUser from an API and storing it in a useState like this:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser[]>();
```

But when I try to use the autocomplete this happens instead of showing all methods that a string have or ICustomImage properties

[image]

```
user.image.width //Because I know it comes with width, this error appears
```

> Property 'width' does not exist on type 'string | ICustomImage'.
> Property 'width' does not exist on type 'string'.

How can I fix this, or make it so that I can use the following

```
user.image.data or user.image.width or user.image.height
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is complaining because `user.image` can be of type `string`, so you can't access the `width` property. You'll need to use the `in` Keyword to check for types in TypeScript.

```js
if ("width" in user.image) {
    const width = user.image.width; // should be ok
}
```

As you'll have to check multiple properties (height, data, etc) you can define a [type guard function](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-check-if-object-implements-interface).

If you're absolutely sure it'll be of type `ICustomImage` then you can cast the value as follow :

```js
const image = user.image as ICustomImage
const width = image.width;
```

Regarding your state name, it should be plurals (because it's an array of user).

```js
// Multiple users
const [users, setUsers] = useState<IUser[]>();
// Single user
const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript has no way to know whether the `image` is a string or your interface object. You haven't narrowed it down for the interpreter and need to do so. Write a type guard to handle this:

```js
interface CustomImage {
    data: string
    width: number
    height: number
}


interface User {
    id: number
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
    image: CustomImage | string
}

const hasCustomImage = (object: any): object is CustomImage => {
    return !!object.data
}

const userCustomImage: User = {
    id: 1,
    firstName: "first",
    lastName: "last",
    image: {
        data: 'data',
        width: 1024,
        height: 768
    }
}

const userStringImage: User = {
    id: 2,
    firstName: "first",
    lastName: "last",
    image: 'image'
}

console.log(`typeguard against custom image object: ${hasCustomImage(userCustomImage.image)}`)
console.log(`typeguard against string image: ${hasCustomImage(userStringImage.image)}`)

const dataImage = hasCustomImage(userCustomImage.image) && userCustomImage.image.data || userCustomImage.image
const stringImage = hasCustomImage(userStringImage.image) && userStringImage.image.data || userCustomImage.image


console.log(dataImage)
console.log(stringImage)
```

Check it out on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbASTzgHMUBvAKGRuQBM4w4AuZbKUE62gd2DrAALViHR4ARtG41BEYCUFgRYyVEoBfSltCRYiFAFVM0ZFVrJ+yiVPMxgUbADk4eCK3adpyADZwnLtzYwDhAuc2BiMlYMbHwiUhQAHyCQrk1KBBwQbGRBPxjcQkiUAF5kAAoccQArCAQlZDgQAE8ASlYq2vqLTDQsQviyZBKAPlMvKAgwdCgQZABCec66sAA6BiYNLUzssGQsaAK44tYjEzKzWktkAEYAGi87BzBnV1YAIifsd4fzX383sh3v8wD8vBEEqxLuYaBsWMgAORwhG-GE0PgCYS3AAMACYACyotGyeSKVgAdgAbAAOLyadI7HIHKAAZWCnEGgTOUGG43CdFYuKJyC+LwCH1FYL+fjFgOBMqlVxOiIhZARWwyWUwOG8EFW3hwJHKAAMwM0AA4QEjoOBQOiNEhwUA5BD9fAWYrIZb1VgAEnIeUwRyKCXKzODnNWqogrXUxtamuyOr1BqNpotVptdodTt2KU4HshyH9gYjxTDxlZ7NCkejsfj2y1ezhnN5pbdIbIFcOHdrxVayAAZIP9pWywko8V1ow4MhEslw72p9HEzkPDXPWV27FOxBu1XUn2EgPh6PoGzD8up3C5wux0uJyvG0ndfrDeUW-3V8m30b1yROVaIA). You could also do an inverse check where your type guard checks to see if the object is a string but this should give you some direction.

Answer (score 0):

You have to narrow the type of `user.image` before accessing its attributes.
If you don't you will only be allowed to access the intersected/shared attributes which are `toString` and `valueOf`.

You could do something like:

```
const someNumber = typeof user.image === 'string' ? user.image.length : user.image.height
```